# How to prove this propensity score weighting leads to averaged treatment effect among the treated?

Tags: conditional-expectation, propensity-scores

Let $Y(1)$ and $Y(0)$ be the potential outcomes under the treatment and the control. $T$ represents the treatment status. We let

$ATT=E\big[Y(1)-Y(0)|T=1\big]$

Next, we let $e(x)$ denote the propensity score. One type of propensity score weighting scheme is: if treated, they get a weight of 1; if not treated, they get a weight of $\frac{e(x)}{1-e(x)}$. We then let

$\Delta=\frac{TY}{1}-\frac{(1-T)Y}{1/\frac{e(x)}{1-e(x)}}$

Now how can we we show that

$E(\Delta)=E\big[\frac{TY}{1}-\frac{(1-T)Y}{1/\frac{e(x)}{1-e(x)}}\big]=E\big[Y(1)-Y(0)|T=1\big]$. So that we know $E[\Delta]$ is unbiased for ATT and weights $(1,\frac{e(x)}{1-e(x)})$ is for ATT.?

I can show that

\begin{align}
E\big[I(T=1)Y\big] &=E\big[I(T=1)Y(1)\big] \, \hspace{1cm} Y(1)=Y \, \text{because of consistency}\\
\end{align}

Now I have a hard time to understand how can we get
\begin{align}
E\big[I(T=1)Y(1)\big]=E\big[Y(1)|T=1\big] 
\end{align}

If so, it follows that
\begin{align}
E\big[I(T=1)Y(0)\big]=E\big[Y(0)|T=1\big]
\end{align}

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you consulted Imben and Rubin's Causal Inference for Statistics, Social, and Biological Sciences: an Introduction (2015), chapter 21?